# MVC - Users must reauthenticate on IIS Recycle

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session-state

I need an app pool recycle to be completely transparent to the users of my web app.

Currently, upon an IIS 7 App Pool recycle all users logged into my web app are kicked out and are required to log back in (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is set to false).  I employ SQL State Server, I use forms authentication and both are configured to use cookies.  I was under the impression that .NET and/or IIS handles authentication of cookies.

However, every time the app pool is recycled Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is set to false (and I've no idea where this occurs) my users are kicked out and are required to log back in.  I can see that the session id remains the same throughout logins, I can also view this session information in the database/state server.

I can't tell if this is a session or a cookie problem.

Please Help!

Logon method:

```
public ActionResult LogOn(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ValidateLogOn(userName, password))
        {
            return View();
        }

        FormsAuth.SignIn(userName, true);  // uses FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
        Session["userName"] = userName;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
```

Custom Controller Attribute:

```
public class CookieAuthorizeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext lvContext = HttpContext.Current;

            if (!lvContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                lvContext.Response.Redirect("~/Account/Logon");
            }
            else
            {
                FormsIdentity identity = (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
                FormsAuthentication.RenewTicketIfOld(identity.Ticket);
            }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

WebConfig:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" slidingExpiration="true" name=".ASPXAUTH" requireSSL="false" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>

<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="ScriptModule" />
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule" />
  <remove name="Session" />
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
  <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add name="NHibernateMvcSessionModule" type="EpnNHibernateBase.NHibernateMvcSessionModule, EpnNHibernateBase" />
  <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" />
  <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
</modules>
```

Comment: I think this might be unclear from your question, but are you running the StateServer on the same machine/VM as the web server?  Because if you are, I believe the StateServer relies on IIS, thus bringing down the AppPool will bring down the StateServer as well.

Comment: Yes, I'm running this locally (on the same server as the App Pool / IIS).

Comment: I just ran across this post and thought I would make a slight correction to the comment above. The StateServer is a separate Windows service so it will continue to run without losing the state data, even if IIS is completely restarted.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was able to find a solution on my own.  The problem was not with how authentication was handled programmatically or how I was authenticating users.  The problem was with how I had configured the authentication in IIS/web.config.

I carefully followed the steps in the links listed below:

[Configuring Forms Authentication (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753252%28WS.10%29.aspx) (Branching out on every related section)

[Configuring Machine Keys in IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755177%28WS.10%29.aspx) <-- This one in particular

After having followed those steps closely I was able to correctly generate a machine key.
This machine key is as follows (with a fabricated key):

```
<machineKey decryptionKey="ASDF3WS545AS5D4F8254A12DAFA5SDF7,IsolateApps" validation="3DES" validationKey="A65A6S5DF46ASD4F89WEF6SAD2F4A68EF4AW65F4D3A2F4AS6DF89A98D4F6A5SD4F6A5SDF46ASD8F4A6S5DF46AS5D4F6AS5DF49AS8DF46AS5D4F6AS5DF46SAD5F,IsolateApps" />
```

Additionally, `httpModules` **and** `system.webServer:modules` sections in the `web.config` required the addition of the following modules:

```
<remove name="Session" />
<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" />
<add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
```

Summary:  From what I gather, cookies were being created and encrypted, but because there was no machine key I was unable to unencrypt the cookie, thus causing the need to reauthenticate.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Just what I needed.  Though I didn't need to add the module config you mentioned -- just the machine keys.

Comment: If you don't specify a machine key, a random key specific to the application pool is automatically generated when the pool starts up.  When the pool is recycled, the key is regenerated, making all of the existing cookies appear invalid.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried storing the sessions in a database so they are persistent even if the process is recycled?
[see here for howto](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604)

Comment: Yes, I initially attempted SQL rather than a local State Service.  I receive the same results.  I've decided to stick with ASP.NET State Service until I get these sessions to persist.  It appears as though the session is being obtained via the service but upon AppPool recycle all users are required to log back in.

Comment: @Alan, SQL Server **will** persist the sessions throughout application pool recycles.

Comment: @Dan I understand that.  The problem is I'm unable to get it to work.  Thus I've chosen to stay with a local ASP.NET State Service (which also will persist through a recycle) as it is the most basic approach.  If anyone could kindly help me in troubleshooting my current setup I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: But, as stated by `ben f`. the problem is that you've tied it into the StateServer, which uses IIS. Therefore, the solution would be to not use that, and look into why the SQL Server solution wasn't working.

Comment: So is there no way to run out-of-proc State Service session management without a recycle bringing down the state server?  I was under the impression this is what State Service is for.  I'm hesitant to move to SQL because I experienced almost identical results with that approach as well.

Comment: So I've switched it over to SQL Server and I'm seeing the session values in the DB (as I did the first time I tried it) but recycling the app pool still results in the need to log back into the web app.  Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Just a note to correct a comment above for future readers. IIS State Service is out of process and it will survive an IIS restart, just like SQL Server State does. Obviously it won't survive a server reboot. The issue was with the machineKey as @alan pointed out later. If you use session state, you will need to use a static machineKey AND out-of-process session state to have a recycle be completely transparent to the user (apart from a slight performance hit).

Answer (score 2):

Reading your post closely, it looks like the real issue is that users are not logged back in automatically. This is handled by cookies assuming you are using forms authentication.

Once a user is logged in, their session state will be restored if you are using SQL to persist it.

To debug cookies, you can use Fiddler or other cookie sniffers.

Posting your web.config would be helpful as well.

Comment: I've switch back to SQL to handle my sessions.  The session ID is persisting. I guess I was mistaking the need to log back in after a recycle for needing to be re-authenticated.  My problem now is the user is required to log back in after the recycle.  Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like a cookie issue. The cookie is how the user is relogged back in. Post your web.config file with the forms auth section.

Comment: @rboarman I've posted the session state and forms auth sections of my config.  Please let me know if there are any other sections you would like to see.

Comment: When you sign in a user, are you passing in true for the create cookie parameter?

Comment: @rboarman Sure am, I'm creating a persistent/durable cookie which will last across different sessions.

Comment: @rboarman I've updated the question with a number of code excerpts.